# JTable Vertical Fill

Tags: java, swing, jtable, populate

Is there a way to populate Jtable vertically? I cant do anything about the structure of my vector

lets say i have an array of integer that looks like {1,2,3,4,5} that is to be inserted on my data parameter in the jtable

i want my output to look like 
[col][col][col][col][col]/n
1/n
2/n
3/n
4/n
5/n

instead of 
[col][col][col][col][col]/n
 1     2    3    4    5

Comment: Have you tried `setValueAt()` with a loop with changing row and constant column?

Comment: ...or implement a TableModel